# Distinguish between two or more keyboards

Tags: python, keyboard-events

I'd like to know how to distinguish between different keyboards.
I'm creating a Python macro app, but even after some research i wasn't able to find anything. I'm running python 3 and I'm on windows 10 64-bit.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `evdev`

https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#reading-events-from-multiple-devices-using-select

```
>>> from evdev import InputDevice
>>> from select import select

# A mapping of file descriptors (integers) to InputDevice instances.
>>> devices = map(InputDevice, ('/dev/input/event1', '/dev/input/event2'))
>>> devices = {dev.fd: dev for dev in devices}
```

You can probably do a list on `/dev/input` to determine the devices?

Comment: this isn't working, i can't install evdev 'cause i'm on windows